# Prevent C++Builder inlining a function

Tags: c++builder

Is there any way to prevent a function being inlined in C++Builder?  E.g. functionality similar to MS's `__declspec(noinline)`.

The reason is that I want the function to have its own symbol in the linker map for debugging purposes.

I am using C++Builder 2006 for this project.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```cpp
#pragma option push
#pragma option -vi-  // prevent inline expansion

void MyFunction()
{
}

#pragma option pop
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no equivalent to `__declspec(noinline)` in C++Builder.  All you can do is simply not implement a function's body code inline with its declaration to begin with.  Keep them separated, such as the declaration in a `.h` file and the body in a `.cpp` file.

Comment: I did that and it still seems to have inlined the function in Release mode. (I only call the function from one place). I'll investigate further